# Having trouble with less than(<) operator in php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a query string and have run into something I can't quite figure out.

Trying to match a string that can contain either < or >, but I'm seeing some weird output only when the string contains a <.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$gt = 'wt>f';
preg_match_all("/([A-Za-z<>]+)/", $gt, $gtmatches);
?>

<pre><?php print_r($gtmatches); ?></pre>
```

Returns as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => wt>f
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => wt>f
        )
)
```

But simply replacing that > with a <, gives really weird output:

**Code:**

```
<?php
$lt = 'wt<f';
preg_match_all("/([A-Za-z<>]+)/", $lt, $ltmatches);
?>

<pre><?php print_r($ltmatches); ?></pre>
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => wt Array
        (
            [0] => wt
```

I've tested this on PHP 5.6.24/IIS 10, and locally on PHP 5.6.32/Apache 2.4.29.

**Solved thanks to iainn (damn you guys are fast!)**

My browser was interpreting the < as the start of a tag, looking at the source, everything is fine.

Comment: it's working for me:- https://eval.in/926067  and  https://eval.in/926069  (two versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to view the `print_r` output in a browser, and it's interpreting the `<` as an HTML tag, up until the end of the `=>` a couple of lines later. If you view the page source rather than the rendered output, you'll see the results you're expecting.

As mentioned in a comment, the regex itself is working fine.

Comment: ahhh haha of course it was that simple, I think I've been coding too long -.- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

< and > are special characters.  Place a backslash before each of them, or use this function on the string before its passed in - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

```
preg_match_all("/([A-Za-z\<\>]+)/", $gt, $gtmatches);
```

Comment: browser was trying to interpret it as a html tag, but thanks a lot for preg_quote, that's gonna come in handy!